# is "root web server" the same as localhost? installing CodeIgniter

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter

I'm trying to install CodeIgniter (I have Mac). I have no experience with Frameworks, but I've read a little about MVC. My goal is to get CodeIgnitor set up so I can use it.

so I download CodeIgniter, then in one tutorial I'm told the following: Copy the file to your server’s web root folder, usually /var/www/ !

In this tutorial: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Introduction-to-CodeIgniter-Framework-P147.html

I am told to "Open your root web server" and put the folder inside.

What is the "root web server"? Is it my htdocs? Where am I supposed to put this folder?

I put the folder into my HTDOCS folder because thats where all PHP files go, but I'm not sure if I did it right.

Comment: htdocs is the typical root web folder if you have Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Please, install the easiest thing in the world [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html)

find folder `xampp/htdocs` (desired **web root folder**) and create folder in it (project name), unzip/unrar/un7z CI in there so your folder structure is going to be

```
xampp/htdocs/project_name/application
                         /system
                         /index.php
```

Open up `project_name/application/config` and go thru all files see them one by one so you know what CI can and can not do it is well explained inside each file what every setting does.

If you are **new** to CI follow this [video tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/)

---

if you are looking for good `.htaccess` file grab this one and change  for whatever you need

note: this file should be in /project_name

note2: also in `config/config.php` set `index_page` to  `$config['index_page'] = '';`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /<your project name>

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

after changing `.htaccess` and `config/config.php` your urls are "nice" 
`localhost/project_name/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2`

finally: it is CodeIgniter not <strike>CodeIgnitor</strike>